# Help with vlc and video capture device error

Tags: video, streaming, capture

I am running vlc 2.0.8 and when I try and stream my cctv camera ( an stk1160 video capture device ) I get this error :-

```
 cvlc /dev/video0
VLC media player 2.0.8 Twoflower (revision 2.0.8a-0-g68cf50b)
[0x7a9618] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[0x7fb5000013b8] main access error: Read error: Invalid argument
[0x7fb5000013b8] filesystem access error: failed to read (Invalid argument)
[0x7fb5000013b8] main access error: File reading failed
[0x7fb5000013b8] main access error: VLC could not read the file (Invalid argument).
[0x7fb500001508] main stream error: cannot pre fill buffer
```

and if I do `vlc /dev/video0` I get this error :-

```
 File reading failed:
VLC could not read the file (Invalid argument). and [0x615108] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0x7f17b40014a8] main access error: Read error: Invalid argument
[0x7f17b40014a8] filesystem access error: failed to read (Invalid argument)
[0x7f17b40015f8] main stream error: cannot pre fill buffer
```

Please help and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

stk1160 capture device with vlc. Paste into a command line:

```
vlc v4l2:///dev/video0
```